# keeping leading zeros and keeping variable as text value instead of numeric

Tags: vbscript

I've got the following VBScript code:

```
WScript.Echo findUser(strUser)
```

It calls the function: `findUser`. It works fine however, when the value of `strUser` is a value like 0001 then for some reason the function strips the zeros and returns only 0 and hence the `findUser` function returns error saying user not found.

Any idea how I can make sure it does not strip any characters? For some reason it is being treated as a numeric value but seeing as user account may not always have numbers only, i would prefer it treats the value of strUser as a text string

*** UDPATE ***

The rest of the code of how I am getting the `strUser` variable is below. It's getting the `strUser` from a CSV file. However, even if I set the `strUser` like this:

```
strUser = 0001
```

it still returns as an interger and removes the leading zeros.

```
Set oConnection = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
Set oRecordSet = CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
oConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= " & sCSVFileLocation & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited"""
oRecordSet.Open "SELECT * FROM " & sCSVFile, oConnection

Do Until oRecordSet.EOF 
    strUser = oRecordSet.Fields.Item(0).value
    WScript.Echo findUser(strUser)

    On Error Resume Next

    oRecordSet.MoveNext 
Loop
```

Comment: How about the rest of your faulty code, where you assign a integer to struser.

Comment: Yeah `findUser()` isn't a built in function so how about showing the code for that then we might be able to help.

Comment: Sorry may have been a miss-communication was asking for the `findUser()` function definition, somewhere in your code you probably have `Function findUser(....)` line and you post that whole definition? If not does it come from somewhere else a library or something perhaps? At the moment we have no context for what `findUser(strUser)` function  is doing.

Comment: @Lankymart the problem doesnt seem to be in the findUser function, because i've completely removed the find user function and i've just tried to  `wscript.echo strUser` and I am still getting it returning 1 instead of 0001. I also tried the following `wscript.echo CStr(strUser)` but still just returns 1

Comment: Sounds like it is already converted to integer before it get's to `oRecordSet.Fields.Item(0).value` it's likely being done by the JET engine, is the `0001` value surrounded by quotes *(`"0001"`)* in the CSV to ensure the provider interprets it as a string and not an integer?

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are listed with leading zeroes in your CSV, but end up as plain integers in your code they most likely are not in double quotes.

```
ID,...
0001,...
0002,...
```

As @Lankymart suspected the JET engine interprets numbers as numbers unless they're explicitly defined as strings by putting them in quotes:

```
ID,...
"0001",...
"0002",...
```

The preferred solution would be to fix the CSV or the process creating the CSV, so that string values are properly defined.

If that isn't possible/feasible for some reason the canonical way to turn an integer into a string with leading zeroes is to prepend the number with an all-zeroes string and cut the result string to the right length:

```
i = 1
s = Right("0000" & i, 4)  's = "0001"
```

Comment: What's the point in having the data one format then having switch and having to switch it back manually? Surely fixing the CSV would make more sense.

Comment: @Lankymart We don't know where the CSV comes from, so we can't tell if fixing it at the source is feasible. The above is a way to deal with the issue without having to involve other parties.